# dateutil / zoneinfo Error When trying to Run py2exe Application

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, py2exe, python-dateutil, zoneinfo

I have a program that I am trying to package as a *.exe using py2exe.  I am stuck on the following error:

```
C:\Users\ME\Desktop\my_gui\dist>my_gui.exe
[Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\ME\\Deskt
op\\my_gui\\dist\\library.zip\\dateutil\\zoneinfo/*.*'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_gui.py", line 29, in <module>
  File "run_sim_gui.pyc", line 3, in <module>
  File "tfm.pyc", line 2, in <module>
  File "init_cond.pyc", line 3, in <module>
  File "policy.pyc", line 1, in <module>
  File "pandas\__init__.pyc", line 7, in <module>
  File "pandas\tslib.pyc", line 12, in <module>
  File "pandas\tslib.pyc", line 10, in __load
  File "pandas\tslib.pyx", line 44, in init pandas.tslib (pandas\tslib.c:79879)
  File "dateutil\zoneinfo\__init__.pyc", line 35, in <module>
  File "dateutil\zoneinfo\__init__.pyc", line 28, in getzoneinfofile
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\ME\\Desktop\\my_gui\\dist\\library.zip\\dateutil\\zoneinfo/*.*'
```

I don't quite understand what this error message means as I can locate the folder just fine:
[image: zoneinfo Folder]

Moving the dateutil folder out of the library.zip folder and placing it in the dist folder (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27705163/error-3-on-dateutil-zoneinfo-using-cx-freeze-and-pandas) for cx_freeze) does not work and produces the following error message:

```
C:\Users\ME\Desktop\my_gui\dist>my_gui.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_gui.py", line 25, in <module>
  File "analysis_gui.pyc", line 3, in <module>
  File "matplotlib\__init__.pyc", line 115, in <module>
ImportError: matplotlib requires dateutil
```

I don't know what to try next.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like maybe you don't have the zoneinfo.tar.gz file in your dateutil. Maybe that's the problem? If building from source, try running `python updatezinfo.py`. Not too familiar with py2exe.

Comment: Are you talking about having zoneinfo.tar.gz in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\dateutil\zoneinfo?  Because if so, I just checked and it is there.  I am not sure what you mean by 'try running `python updatezinfo.py`.  Where would I type that in?